# swig with openmp and python, does swig -threads need extra GIL handling?

Tags: python, numpy, openmp, openblas

I have my C library interfaced with swig.
I can compile it with my setup.py. Here the extension section:

```
surf_int_lib = Extension("_surf_int_lib",
                   ["surf_int_lib.i", "surf_int_lib.c"],
                   include_dirs=[numpy_include],
                   extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp"],
                   extra_link_args=['-lgomp'],
                   swig_opts=['-threads']
                   )
```

In my library I use openmp  for parallelization. When I call my routines, I get the correct number of threads but they all suffer from GIL and are run concurrently. My routines give me the correct output. I was under the impression that `swig -threads` would release GIL when entering the library. So why do my functions not parallelize?

Here is an example of an openmp routine:

```
void gegenbauerval(double *x, int nx, double *cs, int ncs, double alpha, double *f, int nf)
{
    int j;

    #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(j)
    for(j=0;j<nx;++j){
        f[j] = gegenbauerval_pt(x[j],cs,ncs, alpha);
    }
}
```

My interface file does not include any `%threads` or `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` calls. Do I need to release GIL and if so, how would I do that?

**Update:**
I have numpy with openblas installed in a virtualenv, which I use for my calculations. It is the exact same python interpreter as without virtualenv.
If I run following onliner with activated environment, it is not parallelized. However, if I run it with the standard installation, it works.
So I am no longer sure what the real error is.

```
python -c "import surf_int.lib.surf_int_lib as slib;import numpy as np;a=np.random.randn(1e8);c=np.random.rand(23);x=slib.gegenbauerval(a,c,1.5); print x"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I found that this is an issue between openmp and openblas (at least version 0.2.8).

After recompiling openblas 0.2.11 with option `USE_OPENMP=1`, both blas routines from numpy as well as my own extensions using openmp make use of all cpus, set by the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

The issue is maybe related to [this bug report](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/294) and or the changelog entry of [openblas 0.2.9.rc2](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/releases).